# Aligning item of VBox and HBox to different position from other items

Tags: javafx, fxml, dashboard

I'm designing a dashboard in JavaFX FXML. Here is a screenshot of the dashboard:

[image: my dashboard]

Here is FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.farhad.controllers.DashboardMenuController"
      spacing="50.0"
      id="dashboard-menu"
      stylesheets="@../style/dashboard.css">
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="5.0">
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="@../icons/user.png" />
        </ImageView>
        <VBox spacing="5.0" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
            <Label id="user-full-name" text="User full name"/>
            <Label id="user-login-name" text="User login name"/>
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
    <Separator />

    <!--    About User -->
    <VBox spacing="20.0">
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/overview.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Overview"/>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/accounts.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Accounts" />
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/transaction.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Transactions"/>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/products.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Your Products"/>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
    <Separator />

        <!--    Settings -->
    <VBox spacing="20.0">
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/add-account.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Add New Account" />
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/merchant.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Be Merchant"/>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/settings.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="User Settings" />
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" />
        </HBox>
    </VBox>

    <!--  Logout  -->
    <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER">
        <HBox >
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@../icons/logout.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <Label styleClass="dashboard-menu-item-label" text="Logout" />
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" />
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
</VBox>
```

My problem is in the Logout label and a little white vertical separator in each menu item. I want to place the Logout label at the bottom of Parent `VBOX` and a little white vertical separator to the left of `HBOX` as other apps.
How can I modify the code so my dashboard looks like this:

[image: real dashboard]

Suppose that this dashboard has a Logout label at the bottom of the `VBox`

Comment: One option: Put a `<Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>` between the label and separator.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked with both of them. I put <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" /> to Parent VBox before HBox which contains Logout label, it is also okay.